# Can a mobile phone(Android/iOS) application be blocked using a router?

Tags: networking, router

I once blocked a website using a router. The router had the option of blocking websites based on the title of the website. For e.g. [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) could be blocked using the router, by specifying the website in text field.

I don't think the same approach would work for blocking facebook application in a smart phone. Because app comes from the app store(app store can't be blocked using router, based on my knowledge)

So, If I want to block a mobile application through a router, Can it be done?

Comment: Applications still use TCP or UDP to connect to their servers, so if you know the address of the server,  you can block it via router settings.

Comment: *If I want to block a mobile application through a router, Can it be done?* When router receives a packet from the device then it cannot determine what application have sent this packet - there is no such information in the packet. So the task solving is not possible. You may only block the packet based on the data from this packet (protocol, destination address and/or port, packet length, sometimes packed data, etc.) only.

Comment: Certain routers (for example by ASUS) offer the ability to block or shape traffic by category and can identify traffic from specific apps or sites by its properties.

Comment: Actually, routers don't bock anything, firewalls do. With a regular firewall, this would be possible. If your "router" includes some firewall functionality it might have the option, no way of knowing without knowing the exact model.